# Can we decrease the size of a tablerow in a tablelayout in android?

Tags: android, height, row, tablelayout

For a calculator app, I have like 40 buttons and an EditText view but not all are fitting in the emulator. I was wondering if I could decrease the size of table rows.

If it is not possible, Is there any other way?

Here is the code for a tablerow

```xml
  <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="8dp"       
        >       
               <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:text="("
            />

               <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:text=")"
            />
               <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:text="+-"
            />
               <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:text="√"
            />
               <Button 
                android:id="@+id/b24"
                android:text="n!"                   
             />                   
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: if you put customised image in your button background it will fit. default will be slightly bigger.

Comment: How many buttons are you trying to add in each row?

Comment: @sam apparently five buttons. It turns out i can't do more than five. If only I could do six.

Comment: Apply styles @android:style/Widget.Button.Small

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of what you are seeing? (In Eclipse, you can use the ABD's Device Capture button in the Devices window.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont fix your height of table row just put all table row in a Linear layout whose orientation is vertical and give **layout_weight** equal to 1 for all table rows.

Comment: Try using layout height of each row to 0dp and then set layout_weight of all rows to equal.

Comment: You can also try replacing all your table rows with linear layout which is horizontal in orientaion and set each button's layout width and height wrapcontent plus each button 's layout weight equal to one (i.e. to set all horizontal buttons take eqal space) and each row linear layout's weight to be equal to one i.e. giving all row linear layout equal height .By doing so all rows width and height can be controlled to fit in screen.

Comment: `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"`
The above code reduces the size of each button, hence more space :)